# Is the Slayer achievement shared when in a team?

Tags: achievements, guild-wars-2

The game tracks your kills of specific species for the [Slayer Achievement](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Slayer), but is this specific to your character?

Do kills made whilst in a team by any team member count towards this achievement? Would just getting a hit on a mob which is then killed by others still count?

*I understand this might look like two questions, but it's really an either/or style of question :)*

Comment: Why would someone else's kills count towards your achievements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It actually looks like three questions to me....

1. *Is the Slayer achievement specific to a character?* **No**, [Achievements](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Achievement) are not specific to a character, but they *are* specific to an account (even if a contributing character is deleted, the achievement remains).
2. *Do kills by party members count towards one's achievements?* **No**, they don't. Think about it - it would be ridiculous, because others could power-level you (if you received XP) or at least raise your account achievement points without you having to raise a finger or even having to be in the same area. There would be far too much potential for abuse.
3. *Does a single hit on a foe count towards one's achievements?* **Yes**, even if the majority of damage is done by others, your small contribution counts.

Comment: Note that it should be fairly easy for you to confirm all three cases in-game if you're in doubt.

Comment: Just another note on point 3: Of course the foe needs to die in order to give you the "achievement" of killing it. I also _suspect_ (haven't confirmed yet, though) that you need to be a) online and b) in the same map when the foe dies to get kill credit.

Comment: Clarification on 3 - there's some sort of arcane rule that if the mob is close to death you need to deal more damage than you would have needed to if you were the first attacker to get credit for the kill. It's very arcane.

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot test this untill tonight, I'm quite sure I can give you the correct answer to it anyway. I will adapt my answer tonight.

The answer is Yes. Getting a hit on a mob nets you the killcount, the same way you will also get the XP, possible loot, event award (bronze) and/or chest, this will count up to the achievement.

Being in a party is something that doesn't net you the count. A party can actually exist when players are in different maps, so it would be unbalanced to say this was possible.

Comment: Does a team-mates kill count?

Comment: Do you mean being in a party? Then no!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will gain credit towards the relevant slayer achievement as long as you get credit for the kill (indicated by experience gain for non-ambient creatures). No, kills by a different member of your team or party do not count.

In contrast, the weapon master achievements only counts for the player who got the final hit, and only if it was a weapon skill.